# Android app deep linking is not working

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have created an android application for contact management.

You can find link for android app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.saduitcs.vcontact)

Added deep link feature for url: http://www.vcontact.in

It is working correctly for http://www.vcontact.in

It is not working for http://vcontact.in

Any help on this

Comment: What do you have declared in AndroidManifest.xml in the Activity which handles deep links?

Comment: <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.vcontact.in"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add

```
<data android:host="vcontact.in" android:scheme="http" />
```

to your intent filter for the Activity handling the deep link as it is a different host?

Comment: How it make difference with www and without www

Comment: You can have two `data` elements so that it would handle both hosts

Comment: did it work? please update if you could succeed in deep linking